# NestJS SQS Consumer: ChildService Dependency Not Resolving in SQSListenerService

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm encountering an issue with NestJS when using the `nestjs-sqs` library for SQS (Simple Queue Service) message processing. Here's a simplified version of my setup:

I have a `MicroOrchestratorModule` that uses the `SQSListenerService` to process messages from an SQS queue. Inside `SQSListenerService`, I'm trying to use a service called `ChildService` to process the messages, but it seems that the `ChildService` dependency is not resolving correctly.

Here's the updated code:

File: sqs-listener.service.ts

```
// SQSListenerService
@Injectable()
export class SQSListenerService {
    
    constructor(
        private readonly loggerService: LoggerService,
        private readonly childService: ChildService, // Inject ChildService here
    ) { }

    @SqsMessageHandler(SqsQueueEnum.FEATURE_QUEUE, false)
    async startListening(message: any): Promise<void> {
        try {
            const data = JSON.parse(message.Body);
            this.childService.someMethod(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            this.loggerService.unKnownExecption(error)
        }
    }
}
```

File: child.service.ts

```
// ChildService
@Injectable()
export class ChildService {
  someMethod(data: any) {
    // Add your logic here
    console.log('ChildService received data:', data);
  }
}
```

File: micro-orchestrator.module.ts

```
// MicroOrchestratorModule.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    ChildModule, // Imported the module containing ChildService
    SqsModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        AWS.config.update({
          region: configService.get('aws.region'),
          sslEnabled: false,
          accessKeyId: configService.get('aws.access_key_id'),
          secretAccessKey: configService.get('aws.secret_acess_key'),
        });
        return {
          consumers: [
            {
              name: SqsQueueEnum.FEATURE_QUEUE, // name of the queue
              queueUrl: configService.get('aws.sqs.queue_url') + '',
              region: configService.get('aws.region'),
              visibilityTimeout: 30,
            },
          ],
          producers: [],
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
],
  providers: [
    SQSListenerService, // SQSListenerService uses ChildService
    TestService,
  ],
  exports: [SQSListenerService]
})
export class MicroOrchestratorModule {}
```

File: child.module.ts

```
// child.module.ts

@Module({
  providers: [ChildService],
  exports: [ChildService],
})
export class ChildModule {}
```

I've ensured that `ChildService` is provided in the `ChildModule` and that this module is correctly imported into `MicroOrchestratorModule`.

Despite these steps, I'm still facing the error `"Cannot read properties of undefined" when trying to use this.childService.someMethod(data) inside SQSListenerService.`

Complete Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'someMethod')
    at SQSListenerService.startActivity (/Users/avinash.anshu/Project/Josys/smithereens/src/infrastructure/micro-orchestrator/sqs-listener.service.ts:52:31)
    at SQSListenerService.startListening (/Users/avinash.anshu/Project/Josys/smithereens/src/infrastructure/micro-orchestrator/sqs-listener.service.ts:38:18)
    at Consumer.executeHandler (/Users/avinash.anshu/Project/Josys/smithereens/node_modules/sqs-consumer/dist/consumer.js:191:28)
    at Consumer.processMessage (/Users/avinash.anshu/Project/Josys/smithereens/node_modules/sqs-consumer/dist/consumer.js:143:24)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Consumer.handleSqsResponse (/Users/avinash.anshu/Project/Josys/smithereens/node_modules/sqs-consumer/dist/consumer.js:125:57)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Could someone please help me understand why the ChildService dependency is not resolving correctly when processing SQS messages?

Comment: Are you able to access `this.childService` from a different function of `SQSListenerService`?

Comment: yes I was able to access in some other module